# Weird behavior of VPS host

Tags: networking, linux-networking, tcpip, tcpdump, nmap

Hi I noticed strange behavior on my VPS host

- I launch **nmap** on my laptop and scan VPS host

[nmap screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6T3h.png)

- Listed **netstat** on VPS server

[netstat screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykUBH.png)

- Tried to connect to some port
  [connection screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lw6O.png)
- Checked **tcpdump** on VPS server

[tcpdump screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHWRP.png)

- Also checked on **Wireshark** on laptop
  [Wireshark screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSjaD.png)

So it looks like I have some open ports(from the laptop point of view), but cannot see that in the system. What is going on?

Comment: Please don't in future use images to put text into questions: cut-and-paste the text, and use tags to make sure the formatting is preserved.  Thanks!

Comment: At the moment, this looks like a non-question: you have a service running on port 1720, when you connect to it it kicks you off (for purely application-layer reasons).  Your use of netstat will not show this service (try `netstat -an | grep 1720`), so you are confused, but nothing is self-contradictory.  Does that seem fair to you?

Answer (score 0):

I think, that you are looking for this command:

```
netstat -tpln
```

This command will show you listening ports with application, which are those listening port servicing.

Description of parameters:

```
-t: tcp ports (you can try -u for udp ports too)
-p: pids of programs
-l: show listening ports
-n: numerical only
```